# How to echo results with join names from another table using nl2br

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I know how to echo results that are in an array using the following

```
nl2br(str_replace(',', "\n", $row['column-name']))
```

I now have a column in which the listed items (separated by commas) are id numbers that correspond to another table.

How can I echo these results and apply the name associated to that item relative to its id?

I have tried INNER JOIN but I seem to be missing how to perform this correctly.

```
'SELECT * FROM Table1 
 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ColumnName = Table2.ColumnID
 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ColumnID2 = Table3.ColumnID2 <-- This needs to apply names to the number-ids split by the nl2br
 ORDER BY OrderColumn'

<span>'.nl2br(str_replace(',', "\n", $row['table3-column-name-to-replace-table1-columnID2'])).'</span>
```

Thanks for your help.

This is the expected result. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ChGv9qHeJPgtwVcxbqj8ey-1RjVTah28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "I now have a column in which the listed items (separated by commas) are id numbers that correspond to another table."   you should not use CSV in a database.. learn normalisation

Comment: Can you give us an example of a correct match for all three tables? So a row in Table1 that should join to one of Table 2 and Table3

Comment: Table 1 lists coverage areas.
Table 2 lists state names based on Table 1 stateID
Table 3 lists counties for that coverage area, but uses numbers broken by commas, I would like to have it put the names to those numbers

Comment: So `Table1.ColumnID2` is a comma seperated list of `Table3.ColumnID2`?
Like `Table1.ColumnID2 = '123,124,125,126'` and `Table3.ColumnID2 = '123'`, next row would have `Table3.COlumnID2 = '124'` ... ?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to echo Table3.ColumnName to replace the IDs used in Table1.ColumnID2, 

        so, if Table1.ColumnID2, has 3,6,17,22

        Table3.ColumnName would replace as Apple County, Orange County, Grape County, Banana County, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get all `Table3` rows that appear in the list of `Table1` you need to change your JOIN accordingly:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.CoverageArea,
    Table2.stateName as State,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Table3.CountName SEPARATOR '\n') as County
FROM 
    Table1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.State = Table2.ID
    INNER JOIN Table3 
        ON Table1.Counties LIKE Table3.ID+ ',%'
        OR Table1.Counties LIKE '%,' + Table3.ID+ ',%'
        OR Table1.Counties LIKE '%,' + Table3.ID
        OR Table1.Counties = Table3.ID
GROUP BY TABLE1.CoverageArea
ORDER BY TABLE1.CoverageArea ASC;
```

Result would be:

```
[
    ['John Doe', 'Missouri', 'Apple County
                              Orange County
                              Grape County
                              Banana County']
]
```

The down side to this is, that the DB needs to perform multiple text comparisons on each row, meaning that this is a very slow way to do the `JOIN`'s.

The better solution would be to edit `Table3` to hold not only the own ID, but the ID of `Table1` aswell, as a foreign key / parent reference.

```
START TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE Table3 ADD coverageAreaID INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE Table3 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_covarea_state FOREIGN KEY (coverageAreaID) REFERENCES Table1(ID);
UPDATE Table3 SET coverageAreaID = (
    SELECT 
        Table1.ID 
    FROM 
        Table1
    WHERE
        Table1.Counties LIKE Table3.ID + ',%'
        OR Table1.Counties LIKE '%,' + Table3.ID + ',%'
        OR Table1.Counties LIKE '%,' + Table3.ID 
        OR Table1.Counties = Table3.ID 
    LIMIT 1;
);
COMMIT;
```

Like this you can use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.CoverageArea,
    Table2.stateName as State,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Table3.CountName SEPARATOR '\n') as County
FROM 
    Table1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.State = Table2.ID
    INNER JOIN Table3 
        ON Table1.ID = Table3.coverageAreaID 
GROUP BY TABLE1.CoverageArea
ORDER BY TABLE1.CoverageArea ASC;
```

This query will now export the same result as above, but it will be much faster, because it can join the tables with a simple numeric comparison.

Now you should have no problem using your code:

> nl2br($row['County'])

Comment: Structure change is available at this point so I am open to other options.

Comment: Or is it possible, that one state is part in multiple coverage areas? So one coverage area has multiple states and one state has multiple coverage areas.

Comment: I also assumend that the primary key for `Table1` is `int`

Comment: See edited question with link to image mock up.  I tried what you submitted but not sure I have explained the problem correctly.

Comment: Edited my post to meet your specifications

Comment: The only problem I see with your example is that the counties and states table is a table shared by others.  So what might be a coverage area to one person, will be different to another.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Born2Discover Can you specify what you mean by _"that the counties and states table is a tabled shared by others"_ and how it is a downside to you? Can you give me an example of your problem based on an real life example sentance? Like: "It should not be possible that Frank and John, who both live in the Jefferson City, are listed in different coverage areas. Yet Sam, who lives in St. Louis(Missouri), is listed in a different coverage area."

Comment: Have a look at the link to the image I included for reference to what I mean.  It is the best I think I can present to help make my problem clear.